# from django.db.models.sql.aggregates ImportError: No module named aggregates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis

I've been facing a particular problem with aggregates. In this code, sumcase class has a method add_to_query which is intended to instantiate the SQL implementation of the aggregate and sets it as a class variable `(aggregate)` which i'd be using to call the as_sql method in Default `SQL` Aggregate 
`(django/db.models.sql.aggregates.Aggregate)` from another file.

My code (The first file, how I implement aggregate):

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Aggregate
from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Aggregate as SQLAggregate

class SQLsumcase(SQLAggregate):

is_ordinal = True

sql_function = 'SUM'

sql_template = "%(function)s(CASE WHEN %(when)s THEN %(field)s ELSE 0 END)"

def __init__(self, col, **extra):
    if isinstance(extra['when'], basestring):
        extra['when'] = "%s" % extra['when']

    if extra['when'] is None:
        extra['when'] = True

    super(SQLSumCase, self).__init__(col, **extra)


class SumCase(Aggregate):
```

Comment: What Django version are you using

Comment: Django 1.11.12 python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

The  `aggregates` module has been moved to `django.db.models` as I see in version 1.11.17

Don't know if this is the case you encounter but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a module named `aggregates` in `django.db.models.sql` also `Aggregate` is not a class on this sql module. I think you should use:

`from django.db.models.sql import AggregateQuery`

Answer (score 0):

django.db.models.sql.aggregates module is removed from 1.10 version.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it could be suggested as a comment only. Maybe you can expand the answer a bit by clicking [edit] and tell from which version onwards this module is removed.